# How do i get the first value or a PHP multi-demenstional array if I dont know the key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
 Array
 (
  [281] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 1
    )

 )
```

how do i get the first element of this array if i dont know that the key is 281

i figured this would work but no go

```
$my_array[0]
```

Undefined offset

Answer (score 3):

Supposed that you haven't traversed the array yet - use `key()` function to get the key value, and `current` for item value, or move pointer to the begin with `reset()`

```
var_dump(key($my_array));
var_dump(current($my_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple methods, here is one that will work:

```
$output = array_slice( $inputArr, 0, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

use `reset()`. It will give the first element but will reset the internal pointer of the array though